# Physical meaning of the rows and columns matrix representation of operators in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, harmonic-oscillator, matrix-elements

When any operator is written in its matrix form, do the individual rows and columns of the matrices have any physical meaning to them? For example, the rows and columns of momentum and position operators $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{p}$ in Simple Harmonic Oscillator?

Comment: What is a simple harmonic operator? If you meant a simple harmonic oscillator, it is a specification of the Hamiltonian and it doesn't change the position and momentum operators (except for their time evolution if you use Heisenberg picture). Also, matrix elements are basis dependent, so is your question pertaining to any specific basis?

Comment: Are you talking about matrices like $\langle n|x|m\rangle$ where the rows and columns usually represent the $n$th energy eigenstate?

Comment: @DvijD.C. Sorry I meant Oscillator, fixed now. And I meant the position basis

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, that is correct

Comment: Supantho, do you mean the position basis or the energy basis? If you are talking about $\langle n | x |m\rangle$ where $n,m$ are energy eigenstates, as you say you do in your reply to GSmith, then you are talking about energy basis.

Comment: @DvijD.C. Really sorry I meant the Energy basis. Apologies for the confusion. This topic is very new to me.

Comment: No issues! Just wanted to clarify your question :)

Comment: You should edit your question to incorporate the clarifications from the comments. Comment streams like this can (and should) disappear. It clutters the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Physical meaning? In simplified natural units,
$$ H = {1 \over 2} (P^2 + X^2) ~, $$
is manifestly diagonal,  *I*/2 + diag(0,1,2,3,...), for the standard matrix mechanics hermitian expressions
$$
\sqrt{2} X =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
\sqrt{1} & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \sqrt{4} & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix},
 $$
and
$$
\sqrt{2} P  =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -i\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
i\sqrt{1} & 0 & -i\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & i\sqrt{2} & 0 & -i\sqrt{3} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & i\sqrt{3} & 0 & -i\sqrt{4} & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix},
  $$
as you have probably already checked, with eigenvalues 1/2+ *n* for *H*.

You then see that these matrices are extremely sparse,  flanking an *empty diagonal*, and you immediately  intuit their provenance  in creation and annihilator oscillator operators (which raise and lower states by one energy rung). So the first line of *X* tells you it only connects the first excited state to the ground state, etc...

That is, you see that *X* and *P* *only connect states contiguous in energy*, of great utility in perturbation theory. This is at the heart of their physical meaning in QM.

It is also straightforward to verify the basic commutation relation $[X,P]=iI$.

Finally, the Heisenberg time-evolving operators are trivial evolutes of the above matrix elements,
$$
X_{mn}(t) = X_{mn}  e^{i(m - n)t},\qquad P_{mn}(t) = P_{mn}  e^{i(m -n)t}~,
 $$
which should evoke for you Heisenberg's original epochal [Umdeutung argument of 1925](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_mechanics). The  phases of the non vanishing elements are only $\pm  t$, a ***single*** frequency!
$$
\sqrt{2} X (t)=  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &  e^{-it} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
  e^{it}  & 0 & \sqrt{2}  e^{-it} & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & \sqrt{2}  e^{it} & 0 & \sqrt{3} e^{-it}  & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} e^{it}  & 0 & \sqrt{4} e^{-it}  & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix},
 \\      \sqrt{2} P (t) =  
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -i e^{-it} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
i e^{-it} & 0 & -i\sqrt{2} e^{-it}& 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & i\sqrt{2} e^{it} & 0 & -i\sqrt{3} e^{-it} & 0 & \cdots \\
0 & 0 & i\sqrt{3} e^{it} & 0 & -i\sqrt{4}  e^{-it} & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
\end{bmatrix}.
  $$

Comment: thanks! That was very helpful and very clear. One small question, can someone guess intuitively that the matrices of position and momentum cannot have more than two elements in their rows (and columns), without invoking the annihilation and creation operator? What would've happened if the rows (and columns) were to have more than two non-zero elements?

Comment: Not to my knowledge: it is not guessable; it all relies on the ladder operators, and is a peculiarity of the oscillator. If you *already knew* there is only one frequency involved, so rigid rotation in phase space for the quantum system, then you'd reassure yourself of the two last striking formulas: if there were more non vanishing matrix elements, there would be *more* frequencies, e.g. *n*, which you observe in other systems, and there would be no lockstep rigid rotation in phase space.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix represents the operator on a basis set, usually of eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian. They are a bookkeeping method to describe the effect of the operator on these eigenfunctions. Such matrices can be manipulated using linear algebra.